# Rasa Chatbot traing error -> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa

[image]

Getting this error while trying to training.

Comment: If you could update your question with the contents of `config.yml` that would help people answer you better

Answer (score 3):

There is an error in your `config.yml` in the `pipeline` section. It should look like this:

```
language: en
pipeline:
- name: ConveRTTokenizer
- name: ConveRTFeaturizer
- name: RegexFeaturizer
```

sounds like you have either forgotten the dashes, or forgotten the `name` tag, or something like that.